# Bash - how to parse output from running application

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

i have simple application which capturing data from sensor and printing it as output "Received datavalue" and now I need parse all lines and do something with data. I found simple bash script :

```
        set -o pipefail 
    (./myapp) | 
(   
while read; do
            if [ `echo $REPLY | grep -c "Received"` -eq 1 ]; then
              echo Found error: $REPLY >/dev/stderr
              exit 2
            fi;
            echo $REPLY  
 done 
) 
exit $?
```

But it does not work . I ran this script in bash debug mode and it hang after run myapp. Application "myapp" is running in loop and never ends.

Regards.

EDIT: fixed script syntax

I do not know how to do it so i ask google and found script which seems to solve my problem. Original script :

```
set -o pipefail
(echo "foo";  echo "error"; echo "baz") |
(
  while read; do
    if [ `echo $REPLY | grep -c "error"` -eq 1 ]; then
      echo Found error: $REPLY >/dev/stderr
      exit 2
    fi;
    echo $REPLY
  done
)
exit $?
```

It works as i need but it parse comand output. I have application which give output like this:

```
notroot@ro:$ ./myapp
Received 31250
Received 31250
Received 31250
Received 31250
Received 31250
Received 31250
Received 31187
Received 31187
```

Application never ending. Script hang when run application.

Sorry i am not able to explain it more precisely.

EDIT 2:

I found problem using strace - script process is waiting for end child process(myapp) but it never end. So now question is : Does bash can grab lines from app output "in fly"?

Comment: For me is not really clear what you want to do. The above script is not the "cleanest one" - therefore it woud be better to describe the exact problem you facing, example input data and the wanted output. Using "an found script" without understanding it is ... strange?

Comment: Add two semicolons in last line or two line breaks, before "done" and before "exit".

Comment: Are you missing `REPLY` after `read`? Try `while read REPLY; do ...`

Comment: @buff In Bash, *REPLY* is the default variable if one isn't specified.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CodeGnome Thx, I didn't know. Just tried that and you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have gotten the structure of the script backwards. In general, bash itself is not well suited to line-by-line parsing from another program's output. For example,

```
$ ping google.com
```

gives a never ending output of the form:

```
PING google.com (74.125.228.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes … (74.125.228.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=17.6 ms
64 bytes … (74.125.228.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=19.6 ms
64 bytes … (74.125.228.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=14.9 ms
…
```

with one line emitted every second. If you pass its output to a much more capable parser like:

```
$ ping google.com | awk '
    /icmp_seq=5/ { print "error", $8; exit }
    /time=/      { print "ok", $6}'
```

you'll get something like:

```
ok time=16.5
ok time=12.5
ok time=13.0
ok time=16.6
error icmp_seq=5
```

This is vastly simpler than what you are trying to do with that bash `read` loop. Using the right tool for the job really helps. There is a very simple [introduction to awk at Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Awk_Primer/Awk_Command-Line_Examples).

Comment: Understood. I will try with python.